# TypeError: 'FieldFile' object is not callable

Tags: django-rest-framework

I'm getting the `TypeError: 'FieldFile' object is not callable` when trying to get URL of uploaded file:

```
class FetchedDataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   file_fields = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

   class Meta:
      model = FetchedData
      fields = ('model_id', 'config_id', 'config_name', 'file_fields')

   def get_file_fields(self, obj):
      queryset = obj.config_id.config_file() ### 
      return ShoppingListSerializer(queryset, many=True).data
```

The model consists of the following fields:

```
class ShoppingList(models.Model):
   id = models.CharField(max_length=40, primary_key=True)
   name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
   session_id = models.CharField(max_length=40)
   config_file = models.FileField(upload_to=upload_config_file)

   def __str__(self):
       return self.id
```

What should be done with the `queryset` to eventually display uploaded file URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you edit your `get_file_fields` like this ?

```py
class FetchedDataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   file_fields = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

   class Meta:
      model = FetchedData
      fields = ('model_id', 'config_id', 'config_name', 'file_fields')

   def get_file_fields(self, obj):
      queryset = ShoppingList.objects.filter(config_file = obj)
      return [ShoppingListSerializer(cf).data for cf in queryset]
```

Comment: It almost worked: API doesn't crash, however returned array is always empty.

Comment: Maybe you should edit the `queryset`. Then the data might come correctly.

Answer (score 0):

As written, you are trying to execute a field in this line `obj.config_id.config_file()`.
If you want to serialize the object you can simply serialize the one model, you don't need a queryset.

```
class FetchedDataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   file_fields = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

   class Meta:
      model = FetchedData
      fields = ('model_id', 'config_id', 'config_name', 'file_fields')

   def get_file_fields(self, obj):
      return ShoppingListSerializer(obj).data
```

Comment: I had to use an alias for serializers, since there are the ones from `django_restframework` in place: `from django.core import serializers as serial`. Anyway, now the error is: `TypeError: 'FetchedData' object is not iterable`...

Comment: You can use your own serializer instead.. I updated the answer