# Nested serializer doesn't pick up correct ID

Tags: django-rest-framework

There are two models, they are defined this way:

```
class ShoppingList(models.Model):
   id = models.CharField(max_length=40, primary_key=True)
   name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
   session_id = models.CharField(max_length=40)
   config_file = models.FileField(upload_to=upload_config_file)

   def __str__(self):
       return self.id


class FetchedData(models.Model):
    model_id = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    config_id = models.ForeignKey(BillOfMaterial, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=0)
    config_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.model_id
```

And serialized like this:

```
class FetchedDataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   file_fields = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

   class Meta:
      model = FetchedData
      fields = ('model_id', 'config_id', 'config_name', 'file_fields')

   def get_file_fields(self, obj):
      print(obj)
   #  queryset = ShoppingList.objects.filter(config_file = obj)     ## (1)
      queryset = BillOfMaterial.objects.all()                       ## (2)
      return [ShoppingListSerializer(cf).data for cf in queryset]
```

I was advised* to implement the solution marked as (1) in the serializer above, but when it's on, I get responses with an empty array, for example:

```
[
    {
        "model_id": "6553",
        "config_id": "2322",
        "config_name": "Config No. 1",
        "file_fields": []
    }
]
```

Meanwhile, with option (2) turned on and option (1) commented out, I get all the instances displayed:

```
[
    {
        "model_id": "6553",
        "config_id": "2322",
        "config_name": "Config No. 1",
        "file_fields": [
            {
                "id": "2322",
                "name": "First Example",
                "session_id": "9883",
                "config_file": "/uploads/2322/eq-example_7DQDsJ4.json"
            },
            {
                "id": "4544",
                "name": "Another Example",
                "session_id": "4376",
                "config_file": "/uploads/4544/d-jay12.json"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

The `print(obj)` method always gives a `model_id` value. And it should output `file_fields.id`, I guess.

How should I re-build this piece of code to be able to display only the `file_field` with `id` matching `config_id` of the parent?

*This is a follow-up of an issue described here: [TypeError: 'FieldFile' object is not callable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56650553/typeerror-fieldfile-object-is-not-callable)

Comment: `ShoppingList` has no relation with `FetchedData`. Doesn't make sense to filter one against the other which is what #1 does.

Comment: Can you try this  `queryset = ShoppingList.objects.get(pk=obj)` ?

Comment: @adnankaya: I get `DoesNotExist` error: `ShoppingList matching query does not exist.`

Comment: @Linovia: how to establish this relation?

Comment: @AbreQueVoy I have no idea how you models should look like. Just noticing that it won't work with the models you pasted. Beside, #1 and #2 don't even refer to the same model... we are lost

Comment: @Linovia: the models' markup is at the top of this question. Is anything more needed to verify how they look like/work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `FetchedData` model I added this method:

```
def config_link(self):
    return self.config_id.config_file
```

(it binds `config_file` from `ShoppingList` model).

`FetchedDataSerializer` should then look like this:

```
class FetchedDataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    file_link = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = FetchedData
        fields = ('model_id', 'config_id', 'config_name', 'file_link')

    def get_file_link(self, obj):
        return obj.config_link()
```